# Finding derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find derivative of

$$y= \frac{3x^2 - 5x^{\frac{1}{2}} +1}{2x} $$

I tried to solve but couldn't get the required answer ... here's my workings -

$$y' = \frac{2x(\frac{d}{dx}3x^2 - \frac{d}{dx}5x^{1/2} + \frac{d}{dx} 1) - (3x^2 - 5x^{\frac{1}{2}} +1)(\frac{d}{dx}2x)}{4x^2} $$

$$= \frac{2x(6x- \frac{5}{2} x^\frac{-1}{2}) - (6x^2 -10x^{1/2} +2 ) }{4x^2} $$

$$=\frac{12x^2 -5x^{1/2} - 6x^2 + 10x^{1/2}+2}{4x^2}$$

$$=\frac{6x^2 + 5x^{1/2} +2}{4x^2}$$

However this ans is wrong and the answer is -

$$ \frac{6x^{5/2} + 5x - 2x^{-1/2}}{4x^{5/2}} $$

I tried a few times and I still can't get the correct answer . Where did I go wrong . Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is an error sign in your result.The correct result is:
$$
y'=\frac{6x^2+5x^{\frac{1}{2}}-2}{4x^2}
$$

And maybe there is also a typo in the oter result because, if the  $-2x^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ is really $-2x^{\frac{1}{2}}$, than
Multyplying the numerator and denominator of your corrected result by $x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ it is the same:

$$
y'=\frac{(6x^2+5x^{\frac{1}{2}}-2)\cdot x^{\frac{1}{2}}}{4x^2\cdot x^{\frac{1}{2}}} =\frac{6x^{5/2} + 5x - 2x^{1/2}}{4x^{5/2}}
$$

Comment: Yes I understand my error on the sign . But is that the final answer already ?

Comment: I've added to may answer the correct final result.

Comment: What is the use of multiplying both by $x^1/2$ , if sub any values of x into it , the answer will be the same ?